# Method to clear pre-filled data of a ST.future.Component

Tags: sencha-test, sencha-test-2.1

Is there a way to clear an input field while using the `ST.component("locator");` API?

Using `ST.component("locator").setValue("");` results in the following error:

`TypeError: ST.component(...).setValue is not a function...`

PS: Is the old forum now permanently closed? Is there a way to view older questions?

Edit: Seems like the other forum was down yesterday, therefore the PS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an Ext JS field you will need to use the `ST.field` API in Sencha Test, which has a `setValue` method. This method isn't available on the more generic `ST.component` API.

```
ST.field('myfield')
    .setValue('');
```

Or if it's a normal input field (not an Ext JS component), then you can do the following:

```
ST.element('@myfield')
    .execute(function(field) {
        field.dom.value = '';
    });
```